# Adobe After Effects Render Disorted / Preview

Tags: adobe-after-effects

My render is distorted for some reason. The preview looks good trough. Using trapcode, filters etc. but separated into compositions.

The entire render looks like this... Some hints ?
[image]

Comment: Not an expert in AE but this might be an aspect ratio problem with the composition setup and the output type of file you choose to render it in. Can you also give some details on the composition file type and final render type? Codec etc.

Comment: Yeah it have something do do with codec in relation to aspect ratio. Changing codec from lossless to flv or changing aspect ratio helps. This make no sense... Thanks Javi

Comment: You may have already gotten your answer but in case you haven't… perhaps screenshot and share your output settings?